# how to loop through the Restful web service using for loop with a object

Tags: javascript, json

How to loop through the Restfulwebserivice using for loop with a single object. and I don't want to use for each loop so how do i do this. i am not able to get the data by using

```
for(var key in data) {
                    alert(data[key].hotel_geo_node.name);
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
               data[key].hotel_geo_node.name;
           }
```

}

here is the api code.

```
{
  "data": {
    "4325474491990470056": {
        "hotel_geo_node": {
            "name": "The Capitol", 
            "tags": {
                "hotel_chain_code": [
                    "nichendgrp"
                ], 
                "property_type": [
                    "Hotel"
                ], 
                "property_budget_category": [
                    "Luxury"
                ], 
                "others": [
                    "goibibo_hotel"
                ]
            }, 

    }, 

   "4325474491990470057": {
        "hotel_geo_node": {
            "name": "The Capitol", 
            "tags": {
                "hotel_chain_code": [
                    "nichendgrp"
                ], 
                "property_type": [
                    "Hotel"
                ], 
                "property_budget_category": [
                    "Luxury"
                ], 
                "others": [
                    "goibibo_hotel"
                ]
            }, 

    }, 
    "4325474491990470058": {
        "hotel_geo_node": {
            "name": "The Capitol", 
            "tags": {
                "hotel_chain_code": [
                    "nichendgrp"
                ], 
                "property_type": [
                    "Hotel"
                ], 
                "property_budget_category": [
                    "Luxury"
                ], 
                "others": [
                    "goibibo_hotel"
                ]
            }, 
    }
 }
```

}

Comment: `hotel_chain_code` is an array. you must use it as an array.

Comment: how do i do this can you please let me know .?

Comment: The same way you would access an item of any other array. By it's index. `var x = ["a","b","c"]; alert(x[0]); //a`

Comment: i did this but couldn't get the desired one for(var key in data) {
                    alert(data[key].hotel_geo_node.name);
             if(data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
               data[key].hotel_geo_node.name;
           }

Comment: hi kevin , i doing this like var er =data[key];      alert(er[0]); but i am getting error undefined